# ilocを使用した際のindex値の抽出

Tags: python, pandas

以下の様にilocでデータを抽出した場合、
そのindex値を取り出す（2010-03-09）を取り出す方法はありますか？

```py
data.iloc[2500]
Open     925.69
High     927.79
Low      923.60
Close    924.38
Name: 2010-03-09 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

```py
data.iloc[2500].index
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], dtype='object')　←2010-03-09が表示されない
```

Comment: `data.iloc[2500].name` でよいのではないでしょうか…